# Will pip ever point at python3 as opposed to using pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Will I ever find pip to be installing resources for python 3 in the way that pip3 does? I've been making the assumption that when an upgrade to default to python 3 occurs, pip would also be pointed at python 3 resources, but recently went to use a python 3 only docker container built on Red Hat's UBI 8 (I believe) and found pip unavailable and pip3 the only available.

It is an easy fix, but I'm trying to understand the developers intent.

Comment: It already does if you install Python 3 in an virtual environment. `pip3` is just the named used by an installation that expects to be living alongside a Python 2 installation.

Comment: Very odd, because I only have python3 and the anaconda3 installed and only use pip to get packages for my projects and when I check the ones installed, they are indeed installed to python3 environment or even the global python3 depending on what I am working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is distribution specific.

On Arch Linux it already does, on CentOS/Red Hat it does not. [PEP394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) recommends that python3 <s>and pip3</s> be available but leaves it open to the distribution to provide plain python and friends ([check the fourth bullet point](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#for-python-runtime-distributors)).

Until now I have found that distributions follow the same logic with the pip command that they use for the python command.

Comment: Your linked doc doesn't actually refer to pip, only python.

Comment: @Josiah you are right it explicitly refers to "python", "idle", "pydoc". Until now I have found that distributions follwo the same logic for pip that they follow for python.

Comment: Okay, so the distributions have no direction on how to do this from the python team so will do whatever they want basically?

Comment: @Josiah the [4. point](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#for-python-runtime-distributors) leaves it pretty open for the distro :/